# System.getProperty returns null for defined property

Tags: java, properties, system

I have a property `TOOLS_DIR` that i exported in bash

I have the following line in my java file:

```
String toolsDir = System.getProperty("TOOLS_DIR");
```

Why is this returning null? is the a compatibility issue with linux or something?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Environment variables and properties aren't the same thing. If you want to pass in an environment variable as property you have to add the following to your java invocation:

```
-DTOOLS_DIR=$TOOLS_DIR
```

Alternatively, you can use `System.getEnv()`

Answer (score 6):

Java system properties have nothing to do with shell environment variables.

You can assign a java system property when you invoke the virtual machine, for example:

```
java -DTOOLS_DIR=/somewhere org.example.MyClass
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this instead:

```
String toolsDir = System.getenv("TOOLS_DIR");
```

The getProperty(...) method returns java vm properties (like user.dir, java.version).
The getenv(...) method is for environment variables.